# Are there any internal human interface guidelines of successful products freely available?

Tags: gui-design, interface, human-interface-guideline

Many human interface guidelines for the design of apps for iOS and OS X are available.

But I'm searching for internal guidelines for something like Adobe Photoshop or Autodesk 3DS Max. I realise that developers of these products may be hesitant to share all their great ideas, but I think it's a shame if we can't learn from each other.

I've found [a talk about the subject](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-395T) and [some older guidelines (PDF)](http://www.deepsloweasy.com/HFE%20resources/IBM%20UI%20Guide%201988.pdf), but nothing more comprehensive and recent.

Comment: Given Photoshops UI, I'm not convinced the even *have* a HIG standard for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Guidelines are generally available for designers and developers who can freely develop Applications for an **open platform**, say Android and iOS.

If X were to be an open platform, it would require a few standards designers would need to follow in order to get listed under them.

AFAIK, Photoshop/3DSMAX doesn't allow third-party modifications to its software and/or isn't as open to development as Android and iOS's App Store is.

Hence their guidelines remain strictly private and amongst its developers and designers only.

Certainly every company has guidelines (I hope), but they aren't made public if the public cannot openly contribute or if the product doesn't have a demand for contributors.